# Assign HiddenField values programmatically in a loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, loops, webforms

On `default.aspx` I have the following hidden fields:

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="icon1" />
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="icon2" />
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="icon3" />
```

As you can see, the name of the field is the same each time but increments by 1 up to 3.

In my code behind I have been doing this (`if` statements and other code removed for brevity - this is the meat of it):

```
icon1.Value = "Bonus1";
icon2.Value = "Bonus2";
icon3.Value = "Bonus3";
```

Must I assign the `iconX.Value` individually every time like that?  Can I do it all in one shot in a loop (also with everything else removed for brevity)?

```
for (int i = 1; i <=3; i++)
{
    icon(i).Value = "Bonus" + i.ToString();
}
```

Everything I have read leads me to believe this is not possible in C#.  Let's pretend I have 50 `iconX.Value = whatever to assign`.  A loop makes the most logical sense.  Possible?

Answer (score 2):

> A loop makes the most logical sense. Possible?

Yes. Use the [`FindControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method of the page to look up a control by its ID:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
{
    HiddenField field = (HiddenField)this.FindControl("icon" + i);
    field.Value = "Bonus" + i.ToString();
}
```

Note: Because the return type of `FindControl` is `Control`, you must cast the result in order to access properties specific to `HiddenField`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a `asp:panel` in the HTML section.

Then, in the c# code, make a loop and create elements like you describe.

When the element is fully configured, add it to the panel.

**.ASPX file**

```
<asp:Panel ID="panel_controls" runat="server">    </asp:Panel>
```

**C# code**

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    HiddenField myField = new HiddenField();
    myField.ID = "icon" + i;
    myField.Value = "Bonus" + i;
    panel_controls.Controls.Add(myField);
}
```